# Abelian group with cyclic subgroup and cyclic quotient is generated by two elements

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

I have a number of questions that I think are related.

I'm studying Algebraic Topology by Hatcher. I have essentially the same question as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55331/groups-quotient-and-direct-sum-question). When talking about homology groups, the book says that since $H_0 / \tilde{H}_0 \cong \mathbb{Z}$ then $H_0 \cong \tilde{H}_0 \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. The proof in the linked question uses exact sequences. This concept hasn't been introduced at this point in the book yet. The proof also uses the language of category theory, which I'm unfamiliar with. Is there a more elementary proof for this fact, for example using the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups?

(As a side note, I sort of regret not picking up another book with more category theory. A lot of the material on the Internet uses it, but I don't understand it.)

Later in the same chapter, I'm faced with [this exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42434/completing-an-exact-sequence). I don't understand the first part of the answer which says: "If $A$ is an abelian group with a cyclic subgroup $B$ and cyclic quotient group $C = A / B$, then $A$ can be generated by two elements." I don't know why this is true. But it looks somehow related to my first question.

More generally, what should I read to become familiar with such concepts? I've read most of Artin's Algebra, but I feel I have a gap in my knowledge before I can confidently handle such questions.

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you consider the sequence of homomorphisms of groups: $0\to B \to A \to A/B=C \to 0$ inclusion and projection?

Comment: @Sigur Perhaps I've been thinking about this for too long and am missing something obvious. I honestly don't see how this sequence implies that $A$ is generated by two elements.

Comment: The image of the generator of $B$ is a generator to the kernel of the next homomorphism. Since this homomorphism is onto and its image is generated by one element, then you can complete the basis and obtains only to generators.

Comment: The sequence is exact, so the first arrow is zero, the second one is mono, the third one is onto and the last one is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if $H = \langle x\rangle $ and $G/H = \langle \overline{y}\rangle$ are both cyclic, then for any $g \in G$,
$$
\overline{g} = \overline{y}^i \Rightarrow gy^{-i} \in H \Rightarrow gy^{-i} = x^j
$$
and so $g=x^jy^i$, and hence $G$ is generated by $x$ and $y$.

Comment: It's so simple once you put it this way. Thank you (+1). I can follow the same proof to show $H_0 \cong \tilde{H}_0 \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. However, I don't see why this fails if $H_0 / \tilde{H}_0$ is not free (as mentioned in the linked question and demonstrated by a counterexample). Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: Never mind. I'll accept this answer as it answers half of my question. I'll start another more focused question for the other half.